# Splitting aggregate leads to inconsistencies in data

Tags: object-oriented

What I'm going for is something like **GNUCash** or any type of personal finance tracking software that looks similar to this:

[image: GNUCash Main Page]

That is the main page listing all your accounts; then when you click an account it opens up a data grid that allows you to add new transactions. So obviously you want your balance to be updated immediately (i.e. not using eventual consistency).

I initially had an aggregate that consisted of `Account` which held a list of `Transaction`s. It looked something like this:

```
public class Account
{
    public Account(AccountId id)
    {
      _id = id;
    }

    public void AddSubAccount(Account subAccount)
    {
        // do work
    }

    public void RemoveSubAccount(AccountId subAccountId)
    {
        // do work
    }

    public void AddTransaction(Transaction transaction)
    {
        // do work
    }

    public void RemoveTransaction(TransactionId transactionId)
    {
        // do work
    }

    public decimal Balance => computeBalance();

    private decimal computeBalance()
    {
        // loop through all subaccounts
          // loop through all transactions
            // add balances

        // return balance
    }

    private AccountId _id;
    private List<Account> _subAccounts = new List<Account>();
    private List<Transaction> _transactions = new List<Transaction>();
}
```

It was recommended that I follow DDD and split this [potential] large aggregate into 2 separate aggregates:

```
public class Account
{
    public Account(AccountId id)
    {
      _id = id;
    }

    public void AddSubAccount(Account subAccount)
    {
        // do work
    }

    public void RemoveSubAccount(AccountId subAccountId)
    {
        // do work
    }

    public decimal Balance => computeBalance();

    // ISSUE: no longer have access to transactions
    private decimal computeBalance()
    {
        // loop through all subaccounts
          // loop through all transactions
            // add balances

        // return balance
    }

    private AccountId _id;
    private List<Account> _subAccounts = new List<Account>();
}
```

Notice in this split aggregate it's not as easy for the client to just call `account.Balance` to get the balance. It requires some type of service to get the balance. To me it seems odd to have to call `transactionService.computeBalance(accountId)`. This seems very **Anemic Domain Model**.

The next issue I've created is that when a transaction is updated, how do I let everyone know that the balance has changed? This requires the UI to reach out the `TransactionService` again to compute a balance.

So my questions are:

1. Being that I require transactional consistency (I think?), should I keep this large aggregate?
2. Would domain events help my design in any way? Seems that they won't help get passed the issue of relying on services to implement business logic and I don't really want to go the route of Anemic Domain Models.

My goal with this side project is use it as a desktop app and eventually move the business logic layer and data access layer to a server. I have implemented a 3-layer architecture that should allow it to move to a 3-tier architecture with minimal ease.

I have watched Jimmy Bogard's [Crafting Wicked Domain Models](https://vimeo.com/43598193) numerous times. He uses a `List<Offer> AssignedOffers` property inside the `Member`. This allows him to handle the `NumberOfActiveOffers` from inside `Member`. And it seems very close to what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I think the proposed design with splitting up Account and Transaction makes sense. Otherwise, I could be reading  ~1 GB into RAM just to display account names and their balances. I think what actually makes sense is using CQRS and having the IAccountRepository returning a AccountReadModel that holds a Balance property that is already calculated. The ApplicationService could use events to let the UI know when Transactions have been updated or added so the UI can then pull new AccountReadModels.